# Delphi ADO: necessary to clean up parameters?

Tags: delphi, ado

Suppose I have a TADOQuery object that I reuse for different purposes in my program. Do I need to explicitly clean up the parameters when I'm done? Or does that happen automagically when I clear the SQL? *e.g.*

```
  adoGenericQuery.SQL.Text := '';
  adoGenericQuery.Parameters.Clear; // <- Is this redundant?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to clear the parameters manually. When the SQL text is assigned, first the query is closed if it is active, then the parameters are either initialized (if `ParamCheck` is true and the text is not empty) or cleared (if the text is empty).